# Implement Twitter Cards in iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios6

I have integrated twitter in my iPhone app.As i am sharing audio as well ,to enhance this sharing I want to use Twitter cards in my iPhone app.

I cannot get anything more apart from the following URL :
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

Any sort of code lines/tutorial will help a lot

Answer (score 4):

You need a web app to create Twitter Cards.

Twitter cards works by scanning the link that's held within the tweet. If the link leads to a website that has the correct  tags Twitter will create the card.

The process you'd have to take is:

- Upload your audio and other metadata up to a server
- Server responds by sending you back an web link to that page
- Server sets up the relavant  tags for the player card etc.
- Your user's phone then sends the tweet to their twitter account.

This is going to be more complicated for iOS devs who don't do much web development.

Comment: For implementing Twitter Cards :

Step1 : Choose Type of Card to be implemented from the URL  :-
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator

STEP2:Enter value in Various mandatory fields which are :-

a)twitter:card
b)twitter:title
c)twitter:image:src
d)twitter:player(HTTPS URL to iframe player. This must be a HTTPS URL which does not generate mixed content warnings in a web browser..)

Comment: For implementing Twitter Cards :

Step1 : Choose Type of Card to be implemented from the URL  :-
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator


STEP2:Enter value in Various mandatory fields which are :-

a)twitter:card
b)twitter:title
c)twitter:image:src
d)twitter:player(HTTPS URL to iframe player. This must be a HTTPS URL which does not generate mixed content warnings in a web browser..)
e)twitter:player:height
f)twitter:player:width
Then get the HTML in preview .Embed this HTML in your website page and then apply the URL for approval.

Answer (score 3):

Implement Twitter Cards in iPhone,
http://twittercardsios.blogspot.in/2013/11/twitter-summary-cards.html[Implement Twitter Cards in iPhone](http://twittercardsios.blogspot.in/2013/11/twitter-summary-cards.html)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.